# mongo db update a field with another jsondata

Tags: mongodb

i have a mongo db table like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("531963b60748a6078fe4f345"),
    "acces": "172.1.6.2.18",
    "adapter": "Win 9",
    "flavour": "LokiSnap",
    "jobid": "8",
    "os": "VM-WIN7-32",
    "results": "",
    "tests": "Test01"
}
```

here `result` field is `""` .
How can i update this table value `result` with `{"test" : "conenct","os":"osf"}` based on `jobid`

after updating table is

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("531963b60748a6078fe4f345"),
"acces": "172.1.6.2.18",
"adapter": "Win 9",
"flavour": "LokiSnap",
"jobid": "8",
"os": "VM-WIN7-32",
"results": {
    "test": "conenct",
    "os": "osf"
}`,
"tests": "Test01"
```

}

Comment: Do not do what the other answer says. That will replace the whole document, not just the results field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) so that you don't destroy the whole document and just set field/fields

This is the query for update one document

```
db.coll.update(
    {"jobid": "8"}, // the filter based on jobid
    {
        $set: { "results": { "test": "conenct", "os": "osf" } }
    } 
)
```

This is the query for update all documents

```
db.coll.update(
    {"jobid": "8"}, // the filter based on jobid
    {
        $set: { "results": { "test": "conenct", "os": "osf" } }
    } ,
   { multi: true }
)
```

Note:- Here, "coll" is your collection name.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) so you don't destroy the whole document and just set one field

```js
coll.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("531963b60748a6078fe4f345") }, // the filter
    {
        $set: { "results": { "test": "conenct", "os": "osf" } },
    } 
)
```